# After upgrade to Ubuntu Pro no documents are attachable neither to google mail nor to germany gmx mail

Tags: upgrade, email

Yesterday i upgraded to Ubuntu Pro.
Today i wanted to send emails to my pension-fund organization and to the German BfA (national retiree organization) with documents attached.
Some days before sending mail with attached documents was as simple as can be.
Today after upgrading to Ubuntu Pro the mail programs are not uploading the attachments, the planned mail remains empty. Only the main text of Hello and goodbye can be send, what makes no sense.
I must go back to windows.
What is wrong?
Sincerely, Hubert Smuda

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is no "upgrade" with regards to "Pro".  If the mail programs you8're using don't work, then we need to determine what mail platform you're using and debug *that* as it may be specific to that client or the remote mail provider.  What mail client are you using, and what Ubuntu Version do you use?